# How do I roll or wrap up pasta into a log-like shape for presentation?

Tags: pasta, presentation, plating

How do I roll or wrap up pasta into a log-like shape for presentation?

[Example 1](http://omgsohungry.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/img_13501.jpg), [Example 2](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/--yDBjkc7Ok0/UKN25XDcpzI/AAAAAAAAZMc/pJeRqY7Mkss/s640/_DSC0159.jpg), [Example 3](https://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/236x/c3/82/55/c38255d785c8e089625f8bea7330d956.jpg)

[image: Example 3]

Do they use some kind of tool to wrap the pasta around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is in your third picture -- chopsticks.

Grab the bunch with the chopsticks, twirl it around, then slide the chopsticks out.

Comment: Thanks! I also realized that my second picture is from a blog post that also talks about how to twirl pasta: http://www.missyblurkit.com/2012/11/chefs-cuisine-experience-2012-chef.html

Comment: I mostly see Gordon Ramsay do this with tongs, rather than chopsticks. You might find that easier.

Comment: @setek : on cooking shows, normally when I see them spin the pasta with tongs, they're making more of a nest (holding the tongs vertically while spinning), which doees give the pasta shape & height ... but not like what was pictured.

Comment: @Joe oh okay cool, I don't really know I haven't tried it, just a thought :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use the chopsticks to twirl your spaghetti like in this video
[Twirl Spaghetti with chopsticks](http://www.refinery29.com/how-to-plate-spaghetti-perfectly)